# NetBeans 'Tasks' window showing incorrect and old errors - Java

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

Tasks windows is showing a bunch of compilation errors pointing to old errors that i have fixed.
Tried Re-Compiling the file, rebuilding the errors but of no effect ... the number (of Errors) doesn't change.

When i double click an error it takes me to the wrong line since code has been changed.

Using Netbeans 7.1.1 with JDK 1.6

**EDIT 1:** I have tried closing the project, then restarting Netbeans adding it again but of no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to uninstall Netbeans then reinstall it, Deleting the user settings was also important
Exported the Netbeans configurations and then reapplied them .. everything is back to normal.

It is a Netbeans bug, i have posted it in their Bugzilla